# Foreach loop if and else condition not working properly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am stuck at this code, code properly working but in index.blade.php foreach loop not working properly. I am try to show if one user block multiple user then "Unblock" button show in only those user's profile to the one user, else show block button to everyone .

Here Is My UserController

```
public function blockUser(Request $request, $username){

         $blocked = User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
            if (blockuser::where("block_username", "=", $username)->first())
          {
              $blocked = blockuser::where('block_username', $username)->first();
                 $blocked->delete();

          }else{

               $blocked = new blockuser;
                 $blocked->user_username = $request->user_username;
                 $blocked->block_username = $request->block_username;
                 $blocked->b_status = '1';
                 $blocked->save();
                }
               $user = User::where('username', $username)->first();
               $userprofile = userprofile::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
               $blocked = blockuser::where('user_username', Auth::user()->username)->get();
               return view('profile.index',compact('user', 'userprofile', 'blocked'));


   }
```

If data is empty block button is showing and one user block to another user 'Unblock' button also show properly but after click to unblock button 
else condition not working, block button does not show.
What can i do please help me.

Here is profile/index.blade.php

```
    @foreach($blocked as $block)
                   @if(empty($block->user_username ))
                     <a href="#0" class="cd-popup-trigger">Block</a>

                   @else
                        @if(Auth::user()->username == $block->user_username and $user->username == $block->block_username)
                         <a href="#0" class="cd-popup-trigger">Unblock</a>
                         @else
                            <a href="#0" class="cd-popup-trigger">Block</a>
                        @endif
                    @endif
   @endforeach
```

Here Is my block_users table

```
id    user_username   block_username
1      
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
First Make it Sure blockuser is Correct Model Name
//First Solution 
$blocked = User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
$get_blockuser= blockuser::where("block_username", "=", $username)->first();
            if($get_blockuser)// Or Use if(!empty($get_blockuser))
          {
              $blocked = blockuser::where('block_username', $username)->first();
              $blocked->delete();
          }
//Second Solution
$blocked = User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
$get_blockuser= blockuser::where("block_username", "=", $username)->get();
            if(count($get_blockuser)>0)
          {
              $blocked = blockuser::where('block_username', $username)->first();
              $blocked->delete();
          }
```

Comment: controller working fine problem is only foreach loop else condition is  not working. If data is empty block button is showing and one user block to another user 'Unblock' button also show properly but after click to unblock button else condition not working, block button does not show.